# Memory Allocation of Objects and Non Static Variables in Java

Tags: java, object, oop, memory

In school my teacher taught us about objects and non static variables(in Java), and she explained that if we declare a non static global variable, say `int a` in a class and create an object `obj` of the class then we can use the object to access non static variable `a` by using the dot operator(`obj.a`).

Then she said that if we create another object(say, `obj1`) of the same class and access `a` from it using `obj1.a1`, then it will be independent of `obj.a` since obj and obj1 are different objects, hence `obj.a` and `obj1.a` have different memory locations.

My question is, *does the system have a real memory location/address for the object?* Like, is the memory allocation something like allocating an address to the object and storing various non static variables UNDER it(like the object's memory location is being partitioned to accommodate the different non static variables)? Or is the object just a **hypothetical element**, which is used to point to and access the various non static variables, which are the ones actually having REAL memory locations in the storage?

*Tl;dr: Is the storage allocating a memory location for the **object**, or is it doing so only for non static variables under the object, and the object is a hypothetical element not having a real memory location in the storage?*

I would really appreciate it if those who are answering this keep it a bit beginner friendly because I am just in 10th grade now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything needs a memory location: each Object, each non-static variables and static variables too.

If they don't have a memory location they basically don't exist. The Object needs a memory location as well because otherwise we wouldn't know which non-static variables are related to which objects.

Comment: To add to this, the only case in which the actual object is not in memory is when you have not **instantiated** an object but have **declared** it, eg. `Object o;` vs  `Object o = new Object();`. In the latter, the object has been created and stored in a memory location, in the first case there is only a reference made.

Comment: So are there two sets of memory, one for storing objects, and one for storing variables? I am sorry if I sound poorly educated in the topic; I just started learning about the role of memory and storage in Java

Comment: @bruhmonent, there are two places of storage for java: heap and stack. The heap stores objects with their properties(meaning the value for `obj.a` would be here) while the stack stores local variables(eg. an `int` declared in a main) and references to objects(so a reference to `obj` would be here). Objects have their own space but must have a reference in the stack, any independent variables go to the stack directly.

Comment: Heap and stack goes well beyond what was asked therefore decided to keep it simple.

Comment: @bruhmoment I wouldn’t worry too much about that just yet if you are starting out to be honest. It is important for performance sometimes but it is not a must-to-learn if you are getting familiar with the lang and syntax.

Answer (score 1):

1. The hard disk doesn't allocate anything.  The JVM does memory allocation.
2. Static is irrelevant when it comes to memory allocation.  Static just means the value of that variable is available to all instances of the class, if private, or any class accessing that variable, if public.

For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static String value = "myStaticVariable";
}
```

All instances of MyClass could access value and would get "myStaticVariable".  If any of those instances changed that value, all instances would reflect that change.

As for how memory allocation is performed, think of everything within an instanciation as pointer to a memory location.  If it's a primitive, then the appropriate sized amount of memory is allocated and the class instance points that memory location.  Java hides this from us as we really don't need to know the inner workings.  If the variable is to another class then it's pointing another instances which in turn points to its own member variables.  If a variable is re-assigned later, then the original memory allocation is marked for garbage collection to handle at some unforeseen time later.

Comment: The hard disk part was a careless error from my end.

But the rest of your answer doesn't really answer my question, sorry